# How can I stop ssh from trying to create ~/.ssh?

Tags: ssh, freebsd, freenas

I'm working on an rsync-based backup for a FreeNAS system.

Part of the backup process involves logging into the remote system that serves as the backup storage. Whenever I do that, I get the message

```
Could not create directory '/root/.ssh'.
```

I'm assuming this is due to the fact that `/root` is read-only, because when I try to create `~/.ssh` manually, I receive:

```
mkdir: /root/.ssh: Read-only file system
```

Because of this, I have already moved the `known_hosts` file more appropriate for my backup process and am using `-o UserKnownHostsFile` to resolve any issues related to that.

However, `ssh` still tries to create the `~/.ssh` folder when I invoke it. How can I get it to not try to create the folder?

Comment: Does it just normally operate with /root read-only?  In other words, could you briefly mount it read-write to make changes once and have it normally be read-only?

Comment: @kurtm: This seems to be the default. Actually `/` is mounted read-only.

Comment: Okay.  So you *could* mount it read-write, but it's not usually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remount the root filesystem read-write temporarily and make a symbolic link for .ssh that points somewhere where ssh *can* write.  This way you can also do things like add ssh keys in the future, or allow new known_hosts without having to go to extra strenuous steps.  *And* you could get rid of your `-o UserKnownHostsFile` option at the same time.

Comment: +1 simple and effective. Side note another approach in the same vein is just changing the user's defined location for their home directory to be an rw mounted space.

Comment: Your suggestion is probably the way to go. For some reason I assumed that `/root` might be recreated from other data at each reboot, but I never actually verified that. I'll verify this and get back to you :)

Comment: +oliversalzburg That would blow a hole in my idea.  But you could work around that if you find out where it is re-creating `/root` from and changing the original.

Answer (score 8):

The solution mentioned here is good, but I was looking for one which didn't require ~/.ssh to be present or required an attempt for it to be created (running on Windows, distributing a MSYS built ssh.exe, but running on other machines without MSYS/Cygwin installed).

Unfortunately, it appears the routine is hardcoded in the source code, regardless of what value you give to `UserKnownHostsFile`:

```c
    r = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s%s%s", pw->pw_dir,
        strcmp(pw->pw_dir, "/") ? "/" : "", _PATH_SSH_USER_DIR);
    if (r > 0 && (size_t)r < sizeof(buf) && stat(buf, &st) < 0) {
#ifdef WITH_SELINUX
        ssh_selinux_setfscreatecon(buf);
#endif
        if (mkdir(buf, 0700) < 0)
            error("Could not create directory '%.200s'.",
                buf);
#ifdef WITH_SELINUX
        ssh_selinux_setfscreatecon(NULL);
#endif
    }
```

However, it's interesting to note that it attempts to expand the `$HOME` environment variable to determine the home directory.  Since the buffer is around 256 bytes, we can actually bypass the if condition by overflowing the buffer (defining HOME to a string longer than 256 bytes), e.g.:

```
export HOME=$HOME/././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set `$HOME` to `/tmp` or some place where you can write?

Comment: Windows doesn't have `/tmp` unfortunately, or rather, I don't know what it maps to (if it does at all).  `%tmp%` is the Windows equivalent, however it needs to be converted to a MSYS-like path for it to work (eg `/c/Windows/temp` instead of `C:\Windows\temp`), which is a major pain to do in a batch file.  Ideally though, I don't want it creating directories at all.